# how to return a state in next.js 14

Tags: javascript, next.js

Here is my code

```
"use state"
// firebase.js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth"; // Import the authentication module

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).end(); // Method Not Allowed
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const userCredential = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    const user = userCredential.user;

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Authentication successful", user });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed", error });
  }
}
```

I have been encountering this error every approach to fix it prove abortive

[image]

I need help on that

Answer (score 1):

Read [Route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)

```
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

export async function GET(req) {
  const { email, password } = await req.json()

  // ... logic ...

  return NextResponse.json({message: "success"}, {status: 200})
}
```

Comment: I got ```Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json').```

Comment: change `import {NextResponse} from "next";`
to `import {NextResponse} from "next/server";`

Comment: ```Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.```

Comment: The error might be because the `error` is a class
```
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed", error });
  }
```

or in another file, You're passing a non-serialized value from a server component (e.g. page.tsx) to a client component (with `"use client")

Comment: not the solution... I have tried all professional solutions but none worked...